# Double free() occurrence where it should not

Tags: c, pointers, char, free, double-free

I have a frustrating problem for which I can't find an answer to.

I have this function:

```
// Append character to the end of a string
void str_AppendChar(char* s, const char* ch)
{
  // +2 because of 2x '\0'
  char* buff = malloc(strlen(s)+strlen(ch)+2);
  memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));

  // Copy the whole string in buff
  strcpy(buff, s);

  // Append ch at the end of buff
  int len = strlen(buff);
  strcpy(buff+len, ch);

  // Set end of the string
  *(buff+strlen(buff)-3) = '\0';

  strcpy(s, buff);

  free(buff);
}
```

In which for some reason my program tries to execute free two time at the end.

The code in which I use AppendChar() is:(a bit ugly but bear with me)

```
void it_GatherCmd(cmd_Details* lineptr[], char* cmd)
{
  // Used to count number of rows in lineptr
  int nlines;

  Detailptr p;
  char ch;
  char* word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)+256);
  memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));

  nlines = 0;
  while ((ch = *cmd++) != '\n')
  {
      if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\0' )
          str_AppendChar(word, &ch);
      else
      {
          int type = dict_CheckWord(word);

          if (type != -1)
          {
              p = it_CopyInfo(word, type);
              lineptr[nlines++] = p;
          }
          memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
      }
   }
   //EDIT*
   free(word);
}
```

And my main:

```
int main()
{
   cmd_Details* arrCmd[MAXLINES];
   char* str = "just some string";

   it_GatherCmd(arrCmd, str);

   printf("%s", str);
   return 0;
}
```

AppendChar() was working without problems until I created it_GetCharCmd() and used it there. I've spent around 3 hours on this and I can't find the problem. Did some searching on the internet but the things I have found didn't exactly relate to my problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `memset` call in both functions will not work as you expect; `sizeof(buf)` here will be `sizeof(char*)`, not the length of the array.

Comment: For `strcpy(s, buff);` I think there won't be a problem because the data that is going to be used will most likely never reach `sizeof(char)+256`. But I'll keep in mind to optimize it later.
`memset` is used to clear the data in the allocated memory so it can be reused later. After the work is finished the memory is freed.

Comment: The whole procedure is very ineffective. Why do you allocate and free memory locally when all you do is append a char to a word? I think (with the exception of storing the required data in your command structure), you don't need dynamic allocation at all. For example a 256-byte buffer is best created as automatic memory on the steck with `char buf[256]` and you're done.

Comment: Not necessarily the cause of the specific problem, but in `str_AppendChar()` the second parameter is treated like a string (used with `strlen()` and `strcpy()`), while it really just points to a single character, not a null-terminated sequence of characters. So it will try to access the random memory that follows the character, up to the next null it happens to find.

Comment: Here `strcpy(buff+len, ch);` a simple `strcat(buff, ch);` would do.

Comment: `memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));` - huh? do you know what `sizeof` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code.

Firstly, if `str_AppendChar` actually appends a single character as its name implies, why are you giving it a `const char*` which implies a C string? There's zero gain passing a pointer instead of the actual object here, as would be the case with some structs; effectively you still need to push 4 bytes to the stack.

Secondly, as I have pointed out in the comments, the problem is that you don't initialize the allocated buffer properly - `sizeof(buff)` returns well, the size of buff, and buff being a `char*` this is most likely 4. Whilst simply changing `sizeof(buff)` to `strlen(s)+strlen(ch)+2`, which is how much memory you have actually allocated fixed the problem (and since `sizeof(buff)` might have been more than what you have actually allocated, you were writing past that memory), I'd suggest simplifying the function like this:

```
// Append character to the end of a string
void str_AppendChar(char* s, char ch)
{
    size_t sLen = strlen(s);
    char* buff = (char*)malloc(sLen + 2);       // 1 for the appended char, 1 for \0
    //memset(buff, 0, sLen + 2);   //not necessary, we'll overwrite the memory anyway

    // Copy the whole string in buff
    strcpy(buff, s);

    // append our char and null-terminate
    buff[sLen] = ch;
    buff[sLen + 1] = '\0';

    strcpy(s, buff);

    free(buff);
}
```

Note that this code is still bad; it happily assumes that s will be large enough to hold that one extra character, which isn't always the case.

Also regarding your it_gatherCmd function; it should take a `const char*` since it doesn't modify it in any way (and indeed, the way you're calling it, you're giving it a const char*; modifying a string literal is undefined behavior, on Windows you'd probably crash due to violating page permission).

Comment: there's no need to `memset`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath True, Windows will zero it for you, but I feel safer doing it.

Comment: @szczurcio: That's not thze reason: You'll overwrite it immediately after setting it to zero, so it's unnecessary.

Comment: @MOehm Yes, you're right. Changed it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Indeed I didn't do things right, with your version it works. I'll be more careful from now on.

Comment: The part "`malloc` returns `void*` and C won't let you initialize a `char*` with a `void*`, you need to cast it. If this compiles for you, you're likely compiling for C++." is backwards and wrong. It's legal C, but illegal C++. [Don't cast return value of `malloc` in C.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @milleniumbug Oops, right, it should've been the other way round. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are building a string successively while scanning the command. There is absolutely no need to copy the string to append to twice when appending a char. What you are effectively doing, is:

```
void str_AppendChar(char* s, char ch)
{
    int len = strlen(buff);

    s[len++] = ch;
    s[loen] = '\0';
}
```

Note that you determine the string length with `strlen` every time, which will traverse the whole string. Even worse, you don't have any information on the maximum avaiilable buffer size, so despite all your allocating, copying and freeing, the original string might overflow.

Instead of

```
str_AppendChar(word, &ch);
```

use a local buffer in automatic memory:

```
char word[20];
int wlen = 0;
```

and append just like this:

```
if (wlen + 1 < sizeof(word)) word[wlen++] = *cmd;
```

This will leave the word buffer unterminated, so before using it, append it:

```
word[wlen] = '\0';
printf("next word: '%s'\n", word);
```

(Alternatively you could ensure that the string is null-terminated at all times, of course.)

When you reset the buffer for a fresh word, there's no need to `memset` the whole buffer; just reset `wlen` to zero.